# How to set JVM in JBOSS 5?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to set the JVM option in JBoss 5 to this:

```
-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
```

How can I do this?

***UPDATE:***

I tried this ...

I have updated  run.bat file with this entry appended ..

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 **-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser**

Now I get this ERROR  when I start JBOSS server...

...22:12:32,015 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: jbossweb.deployer
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:89)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1000)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:296)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
**Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
    at** org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:100)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.explicit.DeclaredStructure.determineStructure(DeclaredStructure.java:72)
    ... 14 more
**Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.(SaxJBossXBParser.java:97)**
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.(UnmarshallerImpl.java:56)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:96)
    ... 15 more
**Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized.**
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.(SaxJBossXBParser.java:92)
    ... 17 more.

what is the solution now ?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can set this param directly in your jboss `/bin/run.conf.bat` executable. Edit the file and add following to JAVA_OPTS:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.xml.sax.driver=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
```

Comment: Or `run.conf` depending on OS.

Comment: Since we do know what OS he/she uses(?) your previous answer might have been correct as well. :-)

Comment: I am in Windows 7 OS. which file to modify in Windows 7 ?  Can you please tell where I need to modify ?

Comment: @user2553924 updated my answer as per your comments, try and test it. If it works don't forget to upvote/accept my answer.

Comment: I tried . updated  run.bat file .  now getting error ..updated my post. what to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JAVA_HOME in Environment variable in window.

Name : JAVA_HOME
var : your jdk path.

it will ok for all java related application. That is point to the JDK from window.